# Ghostscript problem when removing vectors from large pdf files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying to remove the vectors from some pdf files. Ghostscript (gs) works fine with -dFILTERVECTOR option:

```
gswin64c -o "test_out.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERVECTOR "test.pdf"
```

but when I run this command on large pdf files (larger than 100MB with more than 1000 pages),  I get such error with a blank pdf file as an output:

```
Page 1139
Page 1140
   **** Error: can't process embedded font stream,
        attempting to load the font using its name.
               Output may be incorrect.
Querying operating system for font files...
Substituting font Courier for AVFCLE+CourierNewPSMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Can't find (or can't open) font file NimbusMonoPS-Regular.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Unable to substitute for font.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
Error: /dictfull in --filter--
Operand stack:
   --dict:7/15(L)--   --nostringval--   9   F_2   26049   11   FontObject   --dict:10/18(L)--   false   --dict:4/12(L)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   filter   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   filter   filter   false   1   %stopped_push   1992   1   3   %oparray_pop   1991   1   3   %oparray_pop   1979   1   3   %oparray_pop   1980   1   3   %oparray_pop   filter   filter   1141   1   1277   filter   %for_pos_int_continue   1983   1   7   %oparray_pop   filter   filter   filter   filter   %array_continue   filter   filter   filter   filter   filter   %array_continue   1827   13   10   %oparray_pop
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:734/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:317/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--   --dict:9/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.27: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
Unrecoverable error: VMerror in --.systemvmSFD--
Operand stack:
    --nostringval--  --nostringval--  0
GPL Ghostscript 9.27: ERROR: A pdfmark destination page 1277 points beyond the last page 1139.
```

It seems that the problem is related to a font issue on page 1140. but in fact, if I treat the file as 2 parts, each part works fine with no problem:

part1: pages from 1 to 1000

```
gswin64c -o "test_part1.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERVECTOR -sPageList=-1000 "test.pdf"
```

part2: from 1001 till the last page (around 1900)

```
gswin64c -o "test_part2.pdf" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERVECTOR -sPageList=1001- "test.pdf"
```

So, If I understood well, it seems that it's more related to the number of pages or the size of the pdf file

The pdf files generating the above results are private ones, so I can't upload them. But I have created a 175MB test pdf file [(click here to download)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw4fdk91ahytvq8/test.pdf?dl=0) which give a similir issue:

```
Page 1345
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
Page 1346

 *** ERROR: The font BCDEEE+Calibri is damaged and cannot be used. Switching to a
            last-ditch fallback, text may not render correctly, or at all.

   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
Page 1347
   **** Error: can't process embedded font stream,
        attempting to load the font using its name.
               Output may be incorrect.
Substituting font Helvetica for BCDEEE+Calibri.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
               Output may be incorrect.
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
Page 1348
Error: /VMerror in --filter--
VM status: 4 43671928 45257592
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.27: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Any idea to solve this issue knowing that I'm using the latest version of Ghostscript 9.27 64bit on Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is not related to the use of -dFILTERVECTOR. What happens if you try leaving that off the command line ?

You should also try the most recent Ghostscript code (not yet released) which addresses what may be a related problem.

This [commit](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=fd915a81c605a52f58855bd233c19aaa373b2f69) addressed this [bug report](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=701010) which is similar to what you report here. I suspect you have simply exhausted memory (or at least, memory addressable by Ghostscript).

### Edit

Having tested the file, it exhausts memory for me, using 2GB, after 17452 pages (and doesn't require the FILTERVECTOR switch, as I expected).

There is no solution to this. The pdfwrite device requires to keep a significant amount of content in memory in order to keep processing performance reasonable.

In addition, your file embeds a new copy of each font on every page. Even though each of those fonts has the same name, we must treat each as a unique font. Failing to do so would mean that we might use the wrong font.

So your file has 1980 pages, and 5 fonts on every page, so that's 9,900 fonts. I strongly suspect that the overhead of keeping all these font copies in memory is what is consuming so much. A quick estimate (looking at the decompressed font stream size) would be that the fonts alone would occupy some 792MB of memory. Once you add the Encoding, Widths array, etc this could easily be the major source of memory usage.

Comment: Thank you KenS for your detailed answer. I hope that there will be a solution for this issue in future releases through, for example, treating and writing the output to disk incrementally in a way that prevent reaching to an exhausted memory.

Comment: I'm afraid not, no. The basic problem is that your PDF file defines **lots** of fonts, those fonts all have to be retained in memory, along with their associated furniture, in case they are reused later in the PDF file. There's no way to address this in the current scheme, its inherent in the design, see the documentation https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/VectorDevices.htm#Overview